# htaccess rewrite file to codeigniter controller

Tags: file, codeigniter, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble rewriting external file (outside codeigniter directory) to a codeigniter controller.
It works when accessed directly: http://site.com/codeigniter/index.php/controller/method
It doesn't work in htaccess though (shows codeigniter's 404 error):

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ /codeigniter/index.php/controller/method
```

Is it even possible? I've tried L, QSA and P flags.

Comment: Why you didn't do it with CI Routing ?

Comment: codeigniter and index.php are not in the root direcotry. The address I'm rewriting is. I suppose routing wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: What happen if you put an `?` after index.php ?

Comment: That didn't help so I ended up moving codeigniter to root.